# For what number of vertices is this graph possible?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

Suppose $G$ is an undirected simple Graph with $N$ vertices, one of which has degree $0$, one with degree $1$ and one of degree $2,...,$ and one of degree $N-1$. For which $n$ is this possible?

Is there a way to find the answer without the brute Force method of drawing several graphs?

Comment: Hint: Think about the vertices with largest/smallest degree. What has to be true about their respective neighborhoods?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A vertex with degree zero is isolated. Then the maximum possible degree value in the remainder of the graph is $N-2$. Thus, whenever the "remainder of the graph" exists, such a degree sequence is not possible. So only $N=1$ is feasible.

Drawing graphs is not a bad way to get some intuition into the issue, but the above conflict between maximum and minimum degree vertex should become quickly apparent.

An immediate follow-on result from this is that for any graph of more than one vertex, you will be able to find two vertices with the same degree.

Answer (score 0):

This is only possible for $N = 1$. In order to see this consider the degree sequence $\boldsymbol d = (d_1,\ldots,d_N)$, with $d_i = \text{deg}(i)$ being the degree of vertex $i$. Use the Pigeonhole principle to deduce that is is **not** possible to have a degree sequence of $\boldsymbol d = (1,\ldots,N-1)$ for any undirected graph $G$.